# Spring Boot BrokenPipe / Communications Exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jdbc

i am facing Connection close Exception on my spring boot application.

This is my db configuration:

```
# For auto recconect it is necessary
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow = true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle= true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-return = true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1

spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis = 60000
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-evictable-idle-time-millis = 300000

spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle = 10
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle = 100

# Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time.
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active = 100
```

Exceptions:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 66,612,631
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   66,612,631 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured
>   value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
>   testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing
>   the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the
>   Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this
>   problem.
>
> java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

I have seen many topics about enabling autoReconnect but it is not recommended as far as i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i changed default datasource provider to `dbcp2`, and fixed the bug.

```
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource

# For auto recconect it is necessary
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-on-borrow  = true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-while-idle = true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.test-on-return  = true
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.datasource.dbcp2.time-between-eviction-runs-millis = 60000
spring.datasource.dbcp2.min-evictable-idle-time-millis = 300000

spring.datasource.dbcp2.min-idle = 10
spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-idle = 100
```